# stm32f103c8t6 cannot connect using stlink after upgrade, how to fix?

Tags: stm32f103c8t6

I upgraded the firmware using stlink>upgrade firmware (using cheap stlink v2)
with stm32f103c8t6 connected (boot0 and boot1 are both 0).
After successful upgrade i unplugged and plugged it back and then i can no longer connect to the stm32f103c8t6 using stlink v2

**note**:below images show the screenshots of my firmware. I can upgrade downgrade firmware but no longer connect and program or read the binary, also the software used is st32 stlink-utility 
[firmware version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kakO.png)
[image: during connection]

UPDATE:I noticed that the problem started when i downloaded a blink program using stmcubemx and keil .The program is working successfully but i cannot reprogram or modify it shows st link usb communication error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my Answer to my own question

Steps to follow to solve the problem

1. I have had to pull the BOOT0 pin high during power up to activate the bootloader. Then go to Target menu and Erase chip.
2. Put Boot0 to low and the use stm32cubemx and u need to configure the serial wire on stmcube pinout tab. on pinout tab, click SYS and change debug option to serial wire.
3. Now everything should work as normal.

Comment: I am glad that you got the answer because I had the same situation and ended up buying another STlink so now I have two working STlinks Thank you

Comment: @Tjaartvanaswegen glad it worked for you too